# Viewing/switching efficiently between many Excel worksheets

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel

I have an Excel workbook with over 50 worksheets. This is a necessity and I can't go away from it.

However, I find it hard to:

1. Have an overview of all the worksheets available
2. Quickly jump to a certain worksheet

For the time being, the only thing I can do is to press on the `...` to move to the right and to arrive to a worksheet.

Isn't there a better way to get this overview quickly (something like pressing on the Windows+Tab button?

Comment: If you right-click the < > to the left of the sheet names, you get an 'Activate' dialog where you can jump to another sheet. Does that help?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I was looking for.... for years I am struggling haha

Comment: Turned it into an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you right-click the < > to the left of the sheet names, you get an 'Activate' dialog where you can jump to another sheet.